# Compare MapReduce Performance

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, mapreduce

I already installed hadoop mapreduce in one node and I have a top ten problem.

Let's say I have a 10k pair data (key,value) and search 10 data with the best value.

Actually, I create a simple project to iterate whole data and I need just a couple minute to got the answer.

then, I create mapreduce application with top ten design pattern to solve same problem, and I need more than 4 hour to get the answer. (obviously, I use the same machine and same algorithm to sort)

I think, that probably happens because mapreduce need more service to run, need more network activity, need more effort to read and write to hdfs.
Any other's factor to prove that mapreduce (in that condition) is slower than not using mapreduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mapreduce is slower on a single node setup because only one mapper and one reducer can work on it at  any given time. mapper has to iterate through the each one of the splits and the reducer works on two mapper outputs simultaneously and then on two such reducer out puts ans so on..

so In terms of complexity:

```
for normal project :t(n) = n => O(n)
for mapreduce:t(n) = (n/x)*t(n/2x) => O((n/x)log(n/x)) where x is the number of nodes
```

which do you think is bigger? for single node and multinode..

explanation for mapreduce complexity:

time for one iteration: n

number of simultaneous map function: x since only one can work on each node

then time required for mapping complete data: n/x since n is the time 1 mapper takes for complete data

for reduce job half of the time is required as compared to the previous map since it works on two mapper outputs simultaneously therefore: time = n/2x for x reducers on x nodes

hence the equation that every next step will take half the time than the previous one.

t(n) = (n/x)*t(n/2x)

solving this recursion we get, O((n/x)log(n/x)).

this is not supposed to be exact but an approximation

Comment: thank's for your answer. may i ask you the source of mapreduce complexity? sorry, but i don't get it yet.

Comment: calculated it myself after reading the documentation on apache website. anyway does it answer your question? If yes please mark it as answer. If no, I would be happy to answer your doubt

Comment: Please specify what you do not understand. I will explain accordingly

Comment: i'm sorry antariksha, i wonder technicall answer why hadoop mapreduce in one node need more time to process same problem if i compare it with sequential processing. but, i'm so appreciate your answer, i got new insight about complexity.

Comment: Basically on single node, more iterations are required to do the same thing as a sequential processor but as more nodes are added, mapreducing is a better option as the time is reduced by dividing the proceesing across the cluster

Comment: This is similar to divide and conquer algorithms but this occurs on hardware level

Comment: you are welcome. By the way why did your program take 4 hrs? even on a single node mine took 46 min for 3 gigs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60419/discussion-between-whilda-chaq-and-antariksha-yelkawar).